# Need to select an input name with hook inside

Tags: javascript, string

My code:

```
document.querySelector('input[name=fos_user_registration_form[gender]]:checked')
```

it doesn't work because of [gender].

Do you have an idea to select this type of input ?

Comment: Post the relevant HTML you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Quote the attribute to allow special characters inside.

```
document.querySelector('input[name="fos_user_registration_form[gender]"]:checked')
```